# How to come from $\frac{z^{2}}{z^{2}+1}$ to $\frac{z/2}{z+i}+\frac{z/2}{z-i}$

Tags: partial-fractions

As title says, how to come from $\frac{z^{2}}{z^{2}+1}$ to $\frac{z/2}{z+i}+\frac{z/2}{z-i}$?

Here is what I did:
$\frac{z^{2}}{z^{2}+1}=1-\frac{1}{z^{2}+1}=1-\frac{1}{(z-i)(z+i)}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{z^2}{z^2+1} = z\cdot \frac{z}{z^2+1}$$

Now, use partial fractions to get
$$\frac z{z^2+1} = \frac{\frac12}{z+i} + \frac{\frac12}{z-i}$$
and plug that into the first equation.

Comment: Can someone explain, please, what the problem with my answer is? If there is something I can fix, I want to know. Don't just downvote and run...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly
$$\frac{z^{2}}{z^{2}-1} = \frac{Az}{z+i}+\frac{Bz}{z-i}$$
now cross multiply by $(z+i)(z-i)$ are then take specific values of $z= \pm i$ to find specific values for $A, B$.

**Edit**
I trust is is clear why we split the denominators in that way. I won't go into details as I'll assume that step is trivial. To see why I chose numerators above as simply $Az$ and $Bz$ as noted by @5xum below; don't do that. Take
$$\frac{z^{2}}{z^{2}+1} = \frac{az+b}{z-i}+\frac{cz+d}{z+i}$$

Now cross multiply as I mentioned above giving,
$$z^{2}=(z+i)(az+b)+(z-i)(cz+d)$$
Choose specific values for $z$. Namely, the zeroes of the denominators. Choose $z=i$
\begin{align}
-1 &= 2i(ai+b)+(i-i)(cz+d) \\
\implies -1 &= 2i(ai+b) \\
\implies \frac{i}{2} &= ai+b
\end{align}
This relation shows that $b=0$ since the left hand side is purely imaginary. Thus $a=\frac{1}{2}$. Repeating gives similar expression for $d$ and your result follows.

Comment: but how does one know to use the setup you used? Why not $\frac{az+b}{z+i} + \frac{cz+d}{z-i}$? (I know why, but I think this answer does not explain that...)

Comment: @5xum Fair comment there; I'll edit to reflect this point of view.

Comment: Fair enough. I still think my solution is simpler and better founded in theory a student at (presumably) OP's level should know (like partial fraction decomposition). But this answer is an alternative and is not *wrong*, so I am retracting the downvote.

Comment: @5xum Thanks for retracting the downvote, I agree with you on your other comment, your answer is simpler and probably pitched better for the OP. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Make the ansatz
$$\frac{z^{2}}{z^{2}+1} =\frac{a}{z+i}+\frac{b}{z-i}
=\frac{a(z-i)+b(z+i)}{(z-i)(z+i)}
=\frac{(a+b)z-(a-b)i}{(z-i)(z+i)}$$
Now solve for $a-b=0$ and $a+b=z$. The first gives $a=b,\,$ substitute into the second gives $2a=z,\,$ i.e. $a=b=\frac{z}{2}.$